# Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) Dynamic form with table - How to allow users to paste data across table cell

Tags: aem

I am developing a dynamic form and need to have end users be able to paste data from excel or a table on a web page into a dynamic table in the form.  My table is set up in a flowable section and everything works except when you try and paste, everything pastes into a single cell, not across the entire row.

I am out of ideas how to make this happen.